# Entityframework core load a few records too slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF Core load records too slowly. Where is my code wrong?

This is my code:

it's the entity of GoodsName:

```
public class GoodsName
{
   //..

        public string Name { get;  set; }

  public virtual ICollection<GoodsName_CompanyClient> GoodsName_CompanyClientList { get; set; }

//..
}
```

it's the entity of GoodsName_CompanyClient,it's many-to-many:

```
public  class GoodsName_CompanyClient
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }


        public GoodsName GoodsName { get; set; }


        public Guid FKForGoodsNameId { get; set; }



        public CompanyClient CompanyClient { get; set; }


        public Guid FKForCompanyClientId { get; set; }
    }


var companyClientList=searchModel.CompanyClientList;

 where = where.And(a =>
                      a.GoodsName_CompanyClientList.Any(c => 
                      companyClientList.Any(d => d.Id == c.FKForCompanyClientId))
                  );
```

Comment: What is `where`? Please expand your question to be enough to re-create. (I expect we'll need to look at the generated SQL).

Comment: Please define slow?    how many records in how long

Comment: Most likely you are using EF Core and your query is causing [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation), i.e. loading the whole table in memory and performing the filtering there. Try rewriting the criteria with `Contains` method.

Comment: Where is `And` defined? What is it from?

Comment: @Richard,this is my 'where': Expression<Func<GoodsName, bool>> where = a => a.Id != null;

Comment: @DaImTo, fetch 25 records from 1000,it took 2 or 3 seconds

Comment: @NetMage it's from my extension of the Lamda

Comment: @IvanStoev could you give me more details?

Comment: The idea is to use `Contains` which usually translates to SQL `IN`. e.g. `var companyClientIds = searchModel.CompanyClientList.Select(c => c.Id);` and then `a => a.GoodsName_CompanyClientList.Any(c => companyClientIds.Contains(c.FKForCompanyClientId))`

Comment: @IvanStoev,yeah it's seems faster,Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ivan: is it worth summarising your advice in an answer?